# Gerrit upgrade to 3.4.1 Failed with NoClassDefFoundError ChangeKeyAdapter

Tags: java, gerrit

I came into an error of NoClassFound Error when I exec cmd 'bash gerrit.sh run'.

Before that I have make my Gerrit version upgraded from 3.2.3 to 3.4.1 by

`jar -jar gerrit.3.4.1.jar init  -d  ${MY-GerritSite}`.

And it returned Initialized success.

Here is my Error log when start Gerrit server.

Any help is appreciate.
Thank you.

```
com.google.inject.CreationException: Unable to create injector, see the following errors:

1) [Guice/ErrorInjectingConstructor]: NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gerrit/server/change/ChangeKeyAdapter
  at Log4jMessageLogger.<init>(Log4jMessageLogger.java:38)
  at Log4jMessageLogger.class(Log4jMessageLogger.java:38)
  while locating Log4jMessageLogger
  while locating LifecycleListener annotated with @UniqueAnnotations$Internal(value=59)

Learn more:
  https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/ERROR_INJECTING_CONSTRUCTOR
Caused by: NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gerrit/server/change/ChangeKeyAdapter
        at EventGsonProvider.get(EventGsonProvider.java:80)
        at Log4jMessageLogger.<init>(Log4jMessageLogger.java:40)
        at Log4jMessageLogger$$FastClassByGuice$$745685493.GUICE$TRAMPOLINE(<generated>)
        at Log4jMessageLogger$$FastClassByGuice$$745685493.apply(<generated>)
        at DefaultConstructionProxyFactory$FastClassProxy.newInstance(DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:82)
        at ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:114)
        at ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:91)
        at ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:296)
        at ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
        at SingletonScope$1.get(SingletonScope.java:169)
        at InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:45)
        at FactoryProxy.get(FactoryProxy.java:60)
        at InternalInjectorCreator.loadEagerSingletons(InternalInjectorCreator.java:213)
        at InternalInjectorCreator.injectDynamically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:186)
        at InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:113)
        at InjectorImpl.createChildInjector(InjectorImpl.java:239)
        at Daemon.createSysInjector(Daemon.java:521)
        at Daemon.start(Daemon.java:361)
        at Daemon.run(Daemon.java:279)
        at AbstractProgram.main(AbstractProgram.java:61)
        at java.base/NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at GerritLauncher.invokeProgram(GerritLauncher.java:224)
        at GerritLauncher.mainImpl(GerritLauncher.java:120)
        at GerritLauncher.main(GerritLauncher.java:65)
        at Main.main(Main.java:28)
Caused by: ClassNotFoundException: ChangeKeyAdapter
        at java.base/URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:471)
        at java.base/ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
        at java.base/FactoryURLClassLoader.loadClass(URLClassLoader.java:899)
        at java.base/ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        ... 28 more
```

Comment: Addition info : when version down to 3.7.1 (next to 3.4.0) ,Gerrit runs well. Upgrade to 3.4.0 ,can not start. Neither 3.4.1.

Comment: I  found Gerrit 3.4.x is not compatiable with MessageQueue plugin.I remove it and server back to available.